# What is the Different between Tasks and Test Cases in Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

I am learning the Robot Framework for my automation test cases. I found some code has sections that is Tasks. I want to know if they are different and how to use them in the correct way?

Comment: If you run robot with parameter `--rpa`, log shows test cases as tasks. There is no other difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only difference is the name, and the fact that tests are created in a tests section (e.g. `*** Test Cases ***`) and tasks are created in a tasks section (e.g. `*** Tasks ***`). Otherwise, they are identical.

This is from [the robot framework user guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-tasks):

> For most parts creating tasks works the same way as creating tests and **the only real difference is in terminology**. Tasks can also be organized into suites exactly like test cases.

Answer (score -1):

Test Cases:

Test cases represent specific scenarios or functionalities that you want to test.
They typically consist of a sequence of steps that perform actions and make assertions to verify the expected behavior of the system under test.
Test cases can include keywords, variables, and settings necessary to define and execute the test scenario.
Test cases are executed individually, and their execution status (pass/fail) is reported at the end of the test run.
Tasks:

Tasks are higher-level abstractions that encapsulate a series of related actions or operations to achieve a specific goal.
They can be thought of as reusable sequences of steps that perform a common task or workflow.
Tasks can be composed of multiple keywords and test cases, allowing for modularization and code reuse.
Unlike test cases, tasks are not executed directly. Instead, they are called or invoked from within test cases or other tasks.
Tasks provide a way to organize and structure your test suite by grouping related functionalities together.
How to Use Them Correctly:

Use Test Cases to define individual test scenarios with specific inputs, actions, and expected outcomes.
Use Tasks to organize and modularize your test suite by grouping common functionalities or workflows together.
Define tasks at a higher level of abstraction, focusing on the overall workflow or task that needs to be accomplished.
Use tasks to promote reusability and maintainability by encapsulating common sequences of steps that are used across multiple test cases.
Invoke or call tasks from within test cases as needed to compose complex test scenarios or to reuse common functionalities.